# Java Spring 4 JSON response - missing attributes

Tags: java, spring, jpql

I'm using Spring 4 JPQL / Criteria API to get results for aggregate query, i've created the special constructor in the entity class (with sum and key) and it works without any issues, however the return JSON does not return all the attributes from that class...any idea how I can control what the JSON return structure is? What's even weirder - when running in debug mode then in the following break point:

```
List<ActivityResponse> tActivityResponses =   responseRepository.getTRXByMonths(months);
return tActivityResponses;
```

I am looking at the list and each member of the model class has the correct attributes, like month but month does not appear in the JSON.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more information about were are you storing the json object, which type of Json structure are you using (in java), how do you transform the object to json. This is a little hard to check if you don't provide more information.

Comment: Sure.I am using request mapping with some parameters and get it back as JSON text in the browser,The JSON supposed to return as the entity class itself. does this help?

Comment: Not so much, maybe you could use Jackson library to do the transformation between classes and json objects. It works really good, you can specify by annotations if you want to ignore some of them and works with spring data also.

Comment: In addition to Jackson library you also need @ResponseBody annotation in your request mapping method if you intent to return java object in the JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the replies, i found the answer:
In the REST config class I had to specify config.exposeIdsFor(class name), and that showed all those missing fields.

Thanks.